# stripe payment using codeigniter not getting dynamic amount

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, stripe-payments

Whenever I am adding static amount value in amount field it's working fine
but wherever i making it dynamic it's showing me blank page with no error /Stripe_payment/checkout on this page.

```
require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/Stripe/lib/Stripe.php');

    // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    if(isset($_POST['stripeToken'])){
        $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    }

    $txtPayTotalp = $_POST['txtPayTotalp'];
    $txtPayIdp = $_POST['txtPayIdp'];

    $p = array(
        "amount" => $_POST['txtPayTotalp'],
        "currency" => "aud",
        "card" => $token,
        "description" => "hlkglfjfltylthyjl"
    );

    $charge = Stripe_Charge::create( $p );
```

This is my controller Stripe_payment.php

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" id="form-pay" action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Stripe_payment/checkout'); ?>" method="POST" style="padding-top:10px !important; margin-left: 250px;">
           <input type="hidden" name="txtPayTotalp" id="txtPayTotalp" value="">
           <input type="hidden" name="txtPayIdp" id="txtPayIdp" value="">

        <script id="a1"
            src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="Key"
            data-image="<?php echo base_url('img/hederImg.png'); ?>"
            data-name="PREST LAUNDRY"
            data-description="So Clean............"
            data-amount="2345"
           >
        </script>
    </form>
```

this is my view.
Please help me out from this issue
thanks in advance.

Comment: look at your console, make sure stripe isnt returning any errors  ( probably an invalid interger because your $_POST doesn't contain what you think it does

Comment: when I print array it is showing proper values for all variables.         $charge = Stripe_Charge::create( $p );
This statement is not working properly if I am using dynamic amount.

Comment: Then it looks good, the only thing i can think of is you're not sending enough. You know you have to send in cents right?  Try multiplying your POST by 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
            if(isset($_POST['stripeToken'])){
                $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
            }

            // Create a Customer
            $customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
              "source" => $token,
              "description" => "Test Customer")
            );       

            $txtPayTotalp = $_POST['txtPayTotalp'];
            $txtPayIdp = $_POST['txtPayIdp'];
            $this->session->set_userdata('amount', $_POST['txtPayTotalp']);

            $val = floatval($this->session->userdata('amount'));
            $p = array(
                "amount" => $val,
                "currency" => "usd",
                "card" => $token,
                "description" => "Test Payment"
            );
```

To check datatype of amount I checked vardump($p); amount was in string format.
I used floatval() to change the datatype of amount and it works.

$val = floatval($this->session->userdata('amount'));